# CDATA and quotes in WiX

Tags: wix, cdata

```
<Property Id="PROPERTYUSEDFORCHECKING">
  <RegistrySearch Id='MyRegistry' Type='raw' Root='HKCU' Key='Software\MyApp\Foo'/>
</Property>

<SetProperty Id="SOMEID" After="AppSearch" Value="setValue">
  <![CDATA[PROPERTYUSEDFORCHECKING = "value" ]]
</SetProperty>
```

I try to make a checking wether the PROPERTYUSEDFORCHECKING is equal to "value", but the above keeps returning false (PROPERTYUSEDFORCHECKING = value). How to "include" the double quotes too? I found something similar when publishing, for
instance :

```
<Publish Property="X" Value='"value"'/>
```

But in the CDATA including "value" into ' ' doesn't work.
Any1 have dealt with it and can provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to use CDATA, just use

`PROPERTYUSEDFORCHECKING = "&quot;value&quot;"`